# problem with rosmsg - tutorial

Tags: rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings,

I am using the **Indigo** installation, with Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox.

I am following the ROS tutorials and I am currently having problems with **ros messages**

I follow everything as described

1. Create a new message called Num.msg, under folder beginner_tutorials/msg.
2. Modify the CMakeLists.txt file as described.
3. Run catkin_make

Everything compiles beautifully. I then try to run

```
rosmsg show beginner_tutorials/Num
```

and I get a huge list of locations where ros was searching (unsuccesfully to locate the msg).

Then I run

```
rosmsg list
```

and I don't see my beginner_tutorials/Num in the list.

Am I missing something? How do I add my newly defined msg in the ros list of messages?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189350/problem-with-rosmsg---tutorial/) by [ilymperopo](https://answers.ros.org/users/19967/ilymperopo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you source your workspace?

In your workspace there should be a `devel` directory containing a `setup.bash` try `source setup.bash` and then run your commands again.

Actually this setup.bash file tells ros where to look for messages, nodes, service, etc. and if you do not source it, it will not look in your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2014-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ilymperopo](https://answers.ros.org/users/19967/ilymperopo/) on 2014-08-07**:
thanks
source devel/setup.bash

solved my problem

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-07**:
add that to your .bashrc file in your home folder so it will source everytime you open up a new terminal

**Comment by [ilymperopo](https://answers.ros.org/users/19967/ilymperopo/) on 2014-08-07**:
that's a great idea

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-07**:
That is why it is stated in the tutorials :)

**Comment by [ilymperopo](https://answers.ros.org/users/19967/ilymperopo/) on 2014-08-07**:
Indeed, even though the confusion comes from the fact that sourcing is not repeated in the rosmsg beginners tutorial. But, maybe this serves a purpose, now I know!